# Does Adobe PDF mean that a designer can use a non-postscript printer to proof for fonts etc?

Tags: pdf, adobe-indesign, postscript, proofing

I've had to buy a new printer to replace my wonderful postscript HPLaserjet 4M, because my new mac won't talk to it. I've just realised that the new printer I've ordered is not postscript. (It's a OKI C822n and uses PCL 6 (XL3.0) and PCL5c, SIDM (IBM-PPR, EPSON-FX))

Does that matter now that I can save all my files as print-ready PDFs?

I use my printer to check pages created in InDesign (including placed photoshop and Illustrator files) before sending them to be litho printed. I also use the printer to present to clients and run off short runs of flyers etc.

I am mainly concerned that fonts  will look correct as I design a lot of text-heavy documents such as Annual reports and Accounts, magazines, books etc. I don't mind saving as a PDF before printing if necessary to get an accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your printer to preview fonts, as long as the fonts are saved as outlines instead of embedding the fonts. [This link](http://www.ehow.com/how_8194905_change-outlines-acrobat.html) shows what you need to do in Acrobat 9 Pro. If you use a different PDF writer, you'll need to check the settings there.